# How to create a Work flow for Ignoring Public Holidays in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have already created workflow based on the below link,

[Formula to show differens between dates without weekends and holidays](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88149/formula-to-show-differens-between-dates-without-weekends-and-holidays?newreg=87be8d3d81304849ac287d404d07bca6)

But, I will be getting confused in one column, i.e.,

```
Set variable: Holiday to Holiday:Date
```

How to set the List of holidays dates to the above variable one by one.?

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to create a loop and perform you required operations at each cycle.

if you are unable to do it, but you can extract each element and format them you can use a dictionary

https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow-6956bd6bed9f

Comment: I am new to this one, so I don't have that much of knowledge of Dictionary, So,, is there any way to Compare the list of holidays with start date and End date to get the Number of Days off which exclude Public Holidays and Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: for that you could create a different approach. I would recommend you to create a SharePoint list to store your company's holidays.

Then on your workflow Create a Call http service to extract the count of holidays between the start date and the end date and extract that result to your calculated date.

Comment: I have already stored the company's holidays in SharePoint List, Could you please give me suggestion about this idea. Because i don't have that much knowledge about it. I want to submit this project by this week. Please help me